# Is there onFocused event in textBox WinUI3 .net?

Tags: .net, winui-3

I need event, that triggers when I focus on textBox. Or it can be Left mouse click event also. I just need to change the text when clicking on the textBox. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`GotFocus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.uielement.gotfocus) event.

Sample XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="App5.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App5"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton1">Button 1</Button>
        <Button x:Name="myButton2">Button 2</Button>
        <Button x:Name="myButton3">Button 3</Button>
        <Button x:Name="myButton4">Button 4</Button>
        <TextBox GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Associated C# code:

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace App5
{
    public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as TextBox).Text = "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access one of the elements that composes the `TextBox`. This element has no name, and we can only know it as `FrameworkElement`. To do this, I'm using the `FindDescendants` extension method from the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) NuGet package.

```cs
private void TextBoxControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as TextBox)?.FindDescendants()
        .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(FrameworkElement))
        .FirstOrDefault() is FrameworkElement element)
    {
        element.PointerPressed += Element_PointerPressed;
    }
}

private void Element_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType is PointerDeviceType.Mouse &&
        e.GetCurrentPoint(this).Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed is true)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Mouse left button pressed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to handle only the click event, and also want to handle focus via Tab key operations, you should go with @NineBerry's suggestion. It's way simple.